# Pivot row to column level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe `t` which is the result of a `spark.sql("...")` query. Here is the first few rows from `t`:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | x_id | x_name      | b_app   | status        | has_policy | count |
|------------|------|-------------|---------|---------------|------------|-------|
| 2020-08-18 | 1    | first_name  | content | no_contact    | 1          | 23    |
| 2020-08-18 | 1    | first_name  | content | no_contact    | 0          | 346   |
| 2020-08-18 | 2    | second_name | content | implemented   | 1          | 64    |
| 2020-08-18 | 2    | second_name | content | implemented   | 0          | 5775  |
| 2020-08-18 | 3    | third_name  | content | implemented   | 1          | 54    |
| 2020-08-18 | 3    | third_name  | content | implemented   | 0          | 368   |
| 2020-08-18 | 4    | fourth_name | content | first_contact | 1          | 88    |
| 2020-08-18 | 4    | fourth_name | content | first_contact | 0          | 659   |
```

There is two rows per `x_id` and this is due to grouping on `has_policy`. I would like to pivot `has_policy` and `count` to columns so I can have one row per `x_id` instead. This is how the output would look:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | x_id | x_name      | b_app   | status        | has_policy_count | has_no_policy_count |
|------------|------|-------------|---------|---------------|------------------|---------------------|
| 2020-08-18 | 1    | first_name  | content | no_contact    | 23               | 346                 |
| 2020-08-18 | 2    | second_name | content | implemented   | 64               | 5775                |
| 2020-08-18 | 3    | third_name  | content | implemented   | 54               | 368                 |
| 2020-08-18 | 4    | fourth_name | content | first_contact | 88               | 659                 |
```

I'm not sure if it would be easier to achieve this by converting to Pandas first or if we can operate on the Spark df as it is to get the same result?

---

Data types:

```
t.dtypes
[('yyyy_mm_dd', 'date'),
 ('xml_id', 'int'),
 ('xml_name', 'string'),
 ('b_app', 'string'),
 ('status', 'string'),
 ('has_policy', 'bigint'),
 ('count', 'bigint')]
```

Comment: Since you tagged it with pandas, is pandas based solution fine with you?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yes that's fine. Either a pyspark or pandas solution will do here. However `t = t.toPandas()` will add an index to the dataframe so be wary of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe. [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) is quite straight forward to use when you read the doc.

```py
df.groupBy(
    "yyyy_mm_dd", "x_id", "x_name", "b_app", "status"
).pivot("has_policy", [0, 1]).sum("count")
```

Comment: I get `string indices must be integers` on the `.pivot()`. I've added the dtypes to the original question

Comment: @Someguywhocodes you probably changed something in my code cause it is working fine with your sample data... try removing the `,[0, 1]` part maybe.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes that's a pyspark code btw, not pandas.

Comment: I forgot the comma before the `[]`. It works great, thanks!